# Standard way to control sprite animaition speed in Android games

Tags: android, animation, canvas, sprite-sheet

I have a sprite sheet that has 7 columns. I want to animate (change the column) smoothly. However, if I don't control sprite speed using update % 10, it animates too fast, consequently, the animation is not recognizable. At the moment, I switch between sprite columns every 10 frames, this will not be consistent based on the FPS of the different android devices. Is there a standard way to control sprite animation speed?

```
private final int BMP_ROWS = 1;
private final int BMP_COLUMNS = 7;
 
// sprite update logic
public boolean update(float deltaTime) {

    delayCounterMs += deltaTime;
    animate = true;

    if (update % 10 == 0) {
        currentFrame = ++currentFrame % BMP_COLUMNS;
        int srcX = currentFrame * width;
        src = new Rect(srcX, 0, srcX + width, height);
        dst = new Rect(x, y, x + width, y + height);
       
    }
    update++;
    return false;
}

 // sprite draw logic
 public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    if (animate) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, src, dst, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Based on delayCounterMs? FX     delayCounterMs - update * delay < 0... But update should change inside if... Then update should appear at least after delay

Comment: deltatime is the time difference between the frame. I dont mind using any variable. Is there a sample, that I can use?